# PostgreSQL , REGEX

Tags: sql, regex, string, postgresql

I am interested whether it is possible to extract "hashtags" from a string in an efficient way, using PostgreSQL.

My idea is to replace (*regexp_replace* command) all words that don't start with "#" to empty('').

Could someone provide the regex expression that can be used to accomplish it?

**Input**:

```
hello #i #hate #regex world
```

**Output**:

```
#i #hate #regex
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the spirit of the idea you had in mid, you could use `regexp_replace()` as follows:

```
select regexp_replace(col, '(^|\s)[^#]+(\s|$)', '', 'g')
from mytable
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=257dc506666af864bcba8a7579c1a9d4)**:

```
select regexp_replace(col, '(^|\s)[^#]+(\s|$)', '', 'g')
from (values('hello #i #hate #regex world')) as t(col)
```

```
| regexp_replace  |
| :-------------- |
| #i #hate #regex |
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what characters are allowed in a hash tag, but you can use `regexp_matches()`:

```
select v.str,  regexp_matches(str, '#[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+', 'g')
from (values ('hello #i #hate #regex world')) v(str) ;
```

If you want it as a string, then you can aggregate into a string:

```
select v.str, hashtags
from (values ('hello #i #hate #regex world')) v(str) cross join lateral
     (select string_agg(rm[1], ' ') as hashtags
      from regexp_matches(str, '#[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+', 'g') rm 
     ) rm;
```